# How to map getGsmSignalStrength to a image

Tags: android

getGsmSignalStrength return values in range (0-31, 99). I'd like to map these values into an image showing signal strength. The image is 5 filled (or unfilled) bars like

' '
'|'
'||'
'|||'
'||||'
'|||||'

Is it correct to just test in a linear way like

```
    int x = m_nSignalStrength;

    if (x >= 0 && x <= 31){
        x = 5;
        if (x <= 25) x = 4;
        if (x <= 20) x = 3;
        if (x <= 15) x = 2;
        if (x <= 10) x = 1;
        if (x <= 5) x = 0;
    }
```

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

You can make 5 different drawables, each one is representing one singnal strength state. When just display it on the screen.

Aboud a value interpretion. [getGsmSignalStrength](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/SignalStrength.html#getGsmSignalStrength%28%29) is refering to some document TS 27.007, section 8.5. I think the document is http://www.quintillion.co.jp/3GPP/Specs/27007-950.pdf (just Google on TS 27.007)

Comment: Sorry for being unclear, it's not the drawing I'm asking for. It's how to interpret the signal strength.